# image segmentation and counting open CV and python

Tags: python-2.7, opencv, image-processing, opencv3.0, opencv3.1

i want to identify the objects in the image its size count etc.

[image: sensor image]

The image is something like above i want to identify the objects in the image and get size, count of it is it possible?

Comment: It looks like a processed image, can you please post the unprocessed image.

Comment: https://s31.postimg.org/4kzqn4e8b/index1.png      this is the unprocessed image

Comment: Hello @AmitayNachmani I am in need of someone very good at OpenCV to help me with a personal project. I would pay by the hour. Probably what I am looking for is very/too easy for you. Can we talk by email? alexandergs@yahoo.com